# Model Viewer - GLB - retrieving data from object

Tags: javascript, 3d, gltf, model-viewer

I have some GLB files that I can easily render in the browser and make it interactive (I can rotate it basically)

```
<model-viewer 
  src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb"
  alt="A 3D model of an astronaut"
  auto-rotate
  camera-controls>
</model-viewer>
```

This is a samle, externally hosted GLB file, obviously, but I have my own collection of much more simple GLB files.

Does anyone know a way to not just interact with the GLB, but to retrieve data about the part of the object you're clicking on and pass it to the client side? For example if I have a simple square rendered, is there a way, where if I click on part of it, I can get an "alert" javascript command with the coordinates of where I clicked, or the shape of what I clicked on, or the name of a node (essentially any data from the original GLTF JSON format)?